# How to instantiate an object using it's constructor outside a method java

Tags: java, oop, constructor, language-concepts

I'd like to instantiate an object with it's constructor outside a method. Example:

```
public class Toplevel {

   Configuration config = new Configuration("testconfig.properties");

   public void method1() {

      config.getValue();
      ...etc
   }
}
```

If I do this right now...I get this error..

```
Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

I'd like to do something like this so I could call config anywhere in my class, right now I keep having to instantiate the Configuration objects...there's gotta be a way to do this...any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Configuration class:

```
public class Configuration {

private String mainSchemaFile;


public Configuration() {
}

public Configuration( String configPath ) throws IOException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load( new FileInputStream( configPath ));

    this.mainSchemaFile= prop.getProperty("MAINSCHEMA_FILE");
}
```

Comment: is `Configuration` your own class? does it have a constructor that takes one parameter? Why not create a base constructor for Toplevel and instantiate config there?

Comment: How is your `Configuration` class looks?

Comment: I very much doubt that you'd get that compiler error from that code. I suspect that `Toplevel` extends another class, which has a parameterless constructor which throws `IOException`. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Are you throwing `IOException ` in your `Configuration(String string)` overloaded constructor? If yes, you need to handle the `IOException ` while creating a new instance of `Configuration`

Comment: Yes it's my own class, the constructor throws an I/O exception. Not sure how to throw one when I instantiate outside a method. I'll edit my original post and add the Configuration class

Comment: That code is far longer than it needs to be, and still not complete. All we're looking for is an example which is *complete* (we can copy, paste, compile, see the error) and *short* (no more code than needed to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: I've shortened my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Toplevel object then you have not declared a specific constructor for it and the attribute of Toplevel is instantiated as your code describes it with `Configuration config = new Configuration("testconfig.properties");`

So you do not handle the IoException of the Configuration constructor!
A better way would be to declare a specific constructor of Toplevel like this:

```
public Toplevel(){
    try{
        this.config = new Configuration("testconfig.properties");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: why use "this.config"? config is not a field of class Toplevel

Comment: When you declare something in a class but not in a method then it is a field. You just didn't declared whether it is private, protected or public. In this case it is package-private. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 2):

Your `Configuration` constructor is declared to throw an `IOException`.  Any code that instantiates a `Configuration` using this constructor must catch it.  If you use a variable initializer, then you can't catch it, because you can't supply a `catch` block; there is no block you can put here, only an expression.  There is no method to declare a `throws` clause on either.

Your alternatives:

- Instantiate the `Configuration` in a `Toplevel` constructor.  You can `catch` the exception in the constructor body, or you can declare that constructor that it `throws` the exception.

  ```
  public class Toplevel {
      Configuration config;
      public Toplevel() {
          try {
              config = new Configuration("testconfig.properties");
          } catch (IOException e) {  // handle here }
      }
      // ...
  ```
- Instantiate the `Configuration` in an instance initializer in the `TopLevel` class, where you can `catch` the exception and handle it.

  ```
  public class Toplevel {
      Configuration config;

      {
          try {
              config = new Configuration("testconfig.properties");
          } catch (IOException e) {  // handle here }
      }
      // ...
  ```
- Catch and handle the exception in the `Configuration` constructor, so calling code doesn't have to catch the exception.  This isn't preferred, because you may have an invalid `Configuration` object instantiated.  Calling code would still need to determine if it's valid.

  ```
  public class Configuration {
       // Your instance variables
       private boolean isValid;

       public Configuration( String configPath )  {
           try {
               // Your code that might throw an IOE
               isValid = true;
           } catch (IOException e) {
               isValid = false;
           }
       }
  ```

Comment: Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: @mosawi I've added examples.

Comment: I'm going to try this. I'll report back

Comment: Looks like you have a Configuration constructor inside toplevel? Do you mean a toplevel constructor?

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. I don't have "access" to just one instance of config in my top level class...